# How/Why Does an Event Handler Get an Event Object That Was Not Passed Explicitly

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I am aware that an inline event handler receives an event variable automatically - like this:

```
<button onClick='someFunction(event);'>Act</button>
```

But how does an event handler function automatically have it in scope?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <button id="print-btn">Print</button>

    <script>
        (function(){
            const printBtn = document.querySelector('#print-btn');
            printBtn.addEventListener('click', displayMessage);
            
            function displayMessage(){
                console.log(event); //Prints out a PointerEvent that we did not pass!
            }
        })();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I cannot seem to find any documentation for this behavior.

Weirder still, other functions called by the event handler, still have access to that object.

```
const printBtn = document.querySelector('#print-btn');
printBtn.addEventListener('click', displayMessage);

function displayMessage(){
    console.log("Display", event); //Prints out a PointerEvent that we did not pass!
    doOtherStuff();
}

function doOtherStuff(){
    console.log("Other stuff", event); //Even this one gets it!
}
```

So my questions are:

1. How/why is this so?
2. What scope does the event object have in this case? Is it window?
3. Seeing that the event seems to be passed along the call stack, are there any other cases where parameters are passed like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an event handler (that is not inline), `event` refers to [`window.event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/event) (unless shadowed by another variable).

> The read-only Window property event returns the Event which is currently being handled by the site's code. Outside the context of an event handler, the value is always undefined.

Note that this feature is deprecated and you should not rely on it.

Instead, use the first argument passed to the event handler function.

```js
printBtn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    // e is the event object
});
```

Comment: Right, this was an early Microsoft idea and now everybody is stuck with it, but it was not a good idea.

Comment: Thought it a poor thing to rely on, if only for its low readability. Still, I was surprised to find such a feature even exists.